# wso2 api gateway token caching

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I've been testing the api manager for a while, and currently I'm doing some performance testing on some machines, but noticed poor performance (like 20 req/s). After some checks (the machines are not reaching cpu/mem limits) I noticed a large amount of opened connections from the API Gateway to the Key Manager, even if I'm making the same request with the same token over and over again.

The docs refer to the Gateway Token Cache in the `api-manager.xml` file and `<EnableGatewayKeyCache>true</EnableGatewayKeyCache>` setting, but it's enabled by default, and I'm using the defaults in almost everything else.

Why are there so many connections to the Key Manager and how can I improve the performance?

Comment: 20 req/s is far more behind comparing to API Manager performance. There should be some issue with your setup. What is the backend that you have used for the testing? If backend end can't handle the traffic it would be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

For token caching to work successfully it's required to have caching enabled at Gateway and Resource level. If either one is disabled, it is possible for an API call to hit the Key Manager. By default, Gateway caching and Resource caching are set as enabled in APIM pack.

Could you please check if you have disabled resource caching? If so please make sure to enable resource caching and try again. You can enable resource caching by setting "EnableGatewayResourceCache" value as "true" in api-manager.xml file. You can find more information about API Manager caching in these documents [1][2].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Configuring+Caching

[2] http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2012/10/wso2-api-manager-advanced-validation.html